How to log into apple account inside UTM VM?
I bought a macbook air m3 to legally virtulize mac so I can develop safely without contaminating my host machine with dependencies and possible malwares. I also want to have multiple VMs for different projects.
I was able to boot a macOS VM using UTM but I can't lot into my apple account inside the VM neither create a new one. It appears that apple is using some hardware ID and thinbking this could be a bot or something like that.
How can I log in my apple account inside my VM and use xcode?

This question is similar to: Virtualized macOS via UTM will not allow sign in to the App Store for installation of Xcode?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can't use the App Store or App Store products in a VM, as of the last I know. You should be able to sign in to your Apple Account and use iCloud, provided you're using a virtualization platform that supports it. I don't know whether UTM does, but there are others that do. See:
Sequoia, virtualisation and Apple ID (eclecticlight.co)
Securing virtual machines on Apple silicon (eclecticlight.co)
I haven't tried this myself, but maybe you could run Xcode downloaded from the Apple Developer site rather than the App Store:
Applications (developer.apple.com)

I would encourage you to run your main Mac hardware wish an OS on bare metal. You have superlative isolation now that the macOS system is a sealed snapshot with user modifications layered on top of the immutable OS. Erase all contents and settings to ensure your system is always pristine with a quick discarding of the user volume and making a new one.
Your virtualization approach had merits in the past and may still work on other OS, but macOS has engineered a very trusty solution to your concerns stated. Spend your time thinking about how you back things up, how you automate installing coding tools, and whether git or another source control will let you rapidly start again any time you would discard a VM or start a fresh one.
macOS can boot to external drives, so you can spin up as many OS as you need internally or externally.

Even though I can reboot and feel safer, or erase everything, I still can get totally pwned if I have for example a password manager and install a dependency that has a malware. In my opinion Apple should allow the apple account for virtualization, but thanks for your message, it was helpful anyways
